# Django: What's the use of the context_instance parameter in the render shortcut function?

Tags: django, django-views

[Documentation on 'Render' shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

According to the link above, the **context_instance** parameter is defined as

> The context instance to render the template with. By default, the template will be rendered with a RequestContext instance (filled with values from request and dictionary).

With this definition in mind, I don't see any scenarios that would benefit from supplying the context_instance argument. I mean if I need to provide additional context values I would just add them to the dictionary parameter. I don't know how context_instance can be useful. Please educate me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered my answer? It's more up to date than the others I believe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main scenario is to make certain variables available in your template. For example, the `auth` context processor makes (amongst others) the `user` variable available for use in your template so that you don't have to pass it yourself. Although it's quite a big paragraph, the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) does quite a good job at explaining it.

In a nutshell: by adding `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` to your `render` call, all processors defined in your `settings.py` (under the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable) are executed in order. Each of these processors return a `dict` with variables that are made available in the template. Using the default set, this means you do not have to add e.g. the `user`, `csrf` or `messages` variables yourself: this is done by the processors.

An example for own context processor would be to add your main menu parameters to the template. Say you want to highlight the menu for the current category the user is viewing: by creating your own context processor that determines the current location, it could add some variables in the template that are used by your menu to do the highlighting.

Comment: makes sense to me! Thanks for your thorough explanation.

Comment: But as the documentation says, by default the template will already be rendered to a RequestContext, so this would be unnecessarily setting the same thing that would automatically be set in the call.

Answer (score 9):

Context instance is now deprecated in Django 1.8, and dictionary has been renamed to context.

> **Changed in Django 1.8**:
>   The context argument used to be called dictionary. That name is deprecated in Django 1.8 and will be removed in Django 2.0.
>
> **Deprecated since version 1.8**:
>   The context_instance argument is deprecated. Simply use context.

So if you're using a more recent version of Django, your call to the Render function should be:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"foo": "bar"},
        content_type="application/xhtml+xml")
```

Where `{"foo": "bar"}` is your context. The missing `context_instance` is (I presume) created by default now and populated with the required context of your request.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two things:

1. Backwards compatibility.  You can safely change all references from `render_to_response` to `render`.
2. You don't want the context processors to be run for that particular view, you can pass in `None` in the `context_instance` (saves a bit of overhead.)