# Django render got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm using Python 3.6, and I want to run a project in PyCharm with the Django framework, but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError at /
render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'
Exception Location: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\xaon\app\views.py in home, line 16
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\dj\f\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\xaon',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f',
 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\dj\\f\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 28 Mar 2019 22:20:33 +0000
```

My `view.py` looks like this:

```
def home(request): 
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request, 
        'app/index.html', 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request, { 'title':'Home Page', })
        )
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. There is a problem in xaon\app\views.py line 16. Could you show us this file?

Comment: def home(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(request,
                  'app/index.html',
                  context_instance=RequestContext(request,
                                                  {
                                                      'title':'Home Page',
                                                  }
                                                  )
                  )

Comment: the line 16 is : { 'title':'Home Page', }

Comment: Next time, it would be better to edit your question rather that putting the code in the comments. Doesn't it look a bit squeezed there? ;)

Comment: OK, posting your code as a picture is not a great idea if you need help. Anyone who wants to answer your question will want to copy and paste your code or at least seeing it without a link. I recommend you read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you ask your next question. You'll see that respecting these rules make your question much more likely to find an answer! Good luck!

Comment: thank uu but I have already solved this problem by copying and pasting my code

Answer (score 1):

You're using Django 2.1.7, but the `context_instance` positional argument was [deprecated since version 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#optional-arguments) and removed back in Django 2.0. You should simply [use `context` instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) in your call to the `render()` shortcut function.

For more information on `context_instance` see [this other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910221/django-whats-the-use-of-the-context-instance-parameter-in-the-render-shortcut).